# Atomically read/write int value w/o additional operation on the int value itself

Tags: ios, multithreading, macos, gcc, atomic

GCC offers a nice set of [built-in functions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html) for atomic operations. And being on MacOS or iOS, even Apple offers a [nice set of atomic functions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/KernelIOKitFramework/OSAtomic_h/index.html). However, all these functions perform an operation, e.g. an addition/subtraction, a logical operation (AND/OR/XOR) or a compare-and-set/compare-and-swap. What I am looking for is a way to atomically assign/read an `int` value, like:

```
int a;
/* ... */    
a = someVariable;
```

That's all. `a` will be read by another thread and it is only important that `a` either has its old value or its new value. Unfortunately the C standard does not guarantee that assigning or reading a value is an atomic operation. I remember that I once read somewhere, that writing or reading a value to a variable of type `int` is guaranteed to be atomic in GCC (regardless the size of int) but I searched everywhere on the GCC homepage and I cannot find this statement any longer (maybe it was removed).

I cannot use `sig_atomic_t` because sig_atomic_t has no guaranteed size and it might also have a different size than `int`.

Since only one thread will ever "write" a value to `a`, while both threads will "read" the current value of `a`, I don't need to perform the operations themselves in an atomic manner, e.g.:

```
/* thread 1 */
someVariable = atomicRead(a);
/* Do something with someVariable, non-atomic, when done */
atomicWrite(a, someVariable);

/* thread 2 */
someVariable = atomicRead(a);
/* Do something with someVariable, but never write to a */
```

If both threads were going to write to `a`, then all operations would have to be atomic, but that way, this may only waste CPU time; and we are extremely low on CPU resources in our project. So far we use a mutex around read/write operations of `a` and even though the mutex is held for such a tiny amount of time, this already causes problems (one of the threads is a realtime thread and blocking on a mutex causes it to fail its realtime constraints, which is pretty bad).

Of course I could use a `__sync_fetch_and_add` to read the variable (and simply add "0" to it, to not modify its value) and for writing use a `__sync_val_compare_and_swap` for writing it (as I know its old value, so passing that in will make sure the value is always exchanged), but won't this add unnecessary overhead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `__sync_fetch_and_add` with a 0 argument is indeed the best bet if you want your load to be atomic *and* act as a memory barrier.  Similarly, you can use an `and` with 0 or an `or` with -1 to store 0 and -1 atomically with a memory barrier.  For writing, you can use `__sync_test_and_set` (actually an xchg operation) if an "acquire" barrier is enough, or if using Clang you can use `__sync_swap` (which is an xchg operation with a full barrier).

However, in many cases that's overkill and you may prefer to add memory barriers manually.  If you do not want the memory barrier, you can use a volatile load to atomically read/write a variable that is aligned and no wider than a word:

```
#define __sync_access(x) (*(volatile __typeof__(x) *) &(x))
```

(This macro is an lvalue, so you can also use it for a store like `__sync_store(x) = 0`).  The function implements the same semantics as the C++11 `memory_order_consume` form, but only under two assumptions:

- that your machine has coherent caches; if not, you need a memory barrier or global cache flush *before* the load (or before the first of a group of load).
- that your machine is not a DEC Alpha.  The Alpha had very relaxed semantics for reordering memory accesses, so on it you'd need a memory barrier *after* the load (and after each load in a group of loads).  On the Alpha the above macro only provides `memory_order_relaxed` semantics.  BTW, the first versions of the Alpha couldn't even store a byte atomically (only a word, which was 8 bytes).

In either case, the `__sync_fetch_and_add` would work.  As far as I know, no other machine imitated the Alpha so neither assumption should pose problems on current computers.

Comment: How do I know it is no wider than a word? Going by ISO-C-99, which "int type" is defined to be always exactly as wide as word? As far as I can tell this is not guaranteed for any int type; e.g. on an 8 bit micro controller, an int will still be 16 bit, even though the word size is in fact 8 bit.

Comment: A `sig_atomic_t` should do, even if it is meant for something completely different (signal handlers).  Anyway, I don't think microcontroller backends even implement `__sync_fetch_and_add`, so if you take them into account all bets are off.

Comment: `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` typedefs are guaranteed to be suitable for storing a pointer, which is usually as wide as machine word.

Comment: I will accept this answer, since I finally used fetch_and_add with 0 for an atomic read, which may not be the fastest I can do, but it is at least guaranteed to be robust. Sure, I could use sig_atomic_t, but sig_atomic_t may be only 8 (actually 7) bits (it is only guaranteed to hold values between 0 and 127); this is too little for my purposes. Alone switching from mutexes to atomic operations alone improved performance dramatically according to our benchmarks (thread parallelism is much better than before on multicore systems, resulting in much higher data throughput).

Comment: I've been using OSAtomicOr32(0, (uint32_t *)&value), any issues with this?

Comment: Shawn, it's slower unless your compiler knows how to optimize it (which I doubt).

Answer (score 2):

Volatile, aligned, word sized reads/writes are atomic on most platforms. Checking your assembly would be the best way to find out if this is true on your platform. Atomic registers cannot produce nearly as many interesting wait free structures as the more complicated mechanisms like compare and swap, which is why they are included.

See http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.56.5659&rank=3 for the theory.

Regarding synch_fetch_and_add with a 0 argument - This seems like the safest bet. If you're worried about efficiency, profile the code and see if you're meeting your performance targets. You may be falling victim to premature optimization.